# Laravel Undefined index:

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using I have an issue with my function in laravel and appear to be it's an array issue but since two day's I can't figure out what is the issue the error message is

`Undefined index: eventID`

my function

```
public static function DeleteRow($id){
    $data=DB::select("select * from InOutProducts where eventID=$id;"); 
    $eventID=$data['eventID'];
    $productID=$data['productID'];
    $username=Session::get('key');  
    DB::delete("delete from InOutProducts where eventID=$eventID");
    $row=DB::select("select sum(quantity) as total_quantity from  InOutProducts  where productID='$productID' and InAndOut='1'");
    $PhysicalStock=$row[0]->total_quantity;
    DB::update("update productsStock set physicalStock=$PhysicalStock,lastUpdateBy='$username' where productID=$productID;");`

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::select` returns an array. Try this:

```
$data = DB::select("select * from InOutProducts where eventID=$id;"); 
$data = $data[0];
$eventID = $data->eventID;
```

Comment: the error messaeg now `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: You have to use it as an object afterwards. `$data->eventID; $data->productID;` Answer updated.

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend you take a look at the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) and/or [eloquent models](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent).

Answer (score 0):

if you var_dump $data, it will most likely be null,

You have to remove the semi colin from the query sting.

```
$data=DB::select("select * from InOutProducts where eventID=$id;");
```

to this

```
$data=DB::select("select * from InOutProducts where eventID=$id");
```

Advice, your DeleteRow function is doing

1. select
2. delete
3. select
4. Update

dont your find it a bit too much to do in a single function?
and maybe you can take a look at how Laravel supports querying the database?
[Laravel query the database](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)

Comment: I'm 100% sure the $data is not null because I have test this is the what inside the $data variable `[{"eventID":"160","productID":"45","product_reference":"001","productName":"HP OFFICEJET MAGINTA 5800","brand":"HP","model":"C11234","quantity":"11","location":"Container 1","actiontime":"2015-01-22 08:10:55","username":"osacapcom","InAndOut":"1"}]`  regarding the single function maybe I will do that in my next web application.

Comment: the response you got is a json, you should do json_decode($data) to convert the json to an array.